# How to combine ad-free and ad-supported project in Android/Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, project, targets

I have a app which is ad-supported. I want to make a ad-free version. In order to do so, I would delete the ads from the XML-Files, change the Manifest (no internet connection needed) and I don't know but I may need to delete the SDKs. Code-Wise, I think it could be handled easily with a boolean, which states if ads are enabled.

But what XML files, SDKs and Android Manifest? Is there a convinient way to handle this?

Comment: What about making a common `library` project with the shared functionalists/activities between both apps and then create two projects that use it?

Comment: In the long run I would recommend Maven for this, a lot of learning and configuration to do but (IMO) in the end worth it